# What is this type of unwarranted assumption called?

Tags: conditionals

> If Jim is taller than Susan, all tall people are named Jim.

In this condition the protasis has an apparent relationship with the apodosis, but regardless of whether protasis is true or false, it has no bearing on the validity of the apodosis.

I'm trying to find the term to describe this unwarranted assumption.

The following terms are close but don't quite fit:

- **false implication** - A related, but assumed implication that is not necessarily true.
- **counterfactual condition** - a condition where the protasis is presumed false (but may not actually be so) and the apodosis describes what would have been if the protasis were true.
- **false dichotomy** - a apodosis that assumes only two possible options when more are possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about logic, not English.

Comment: I'd counter that the question is for a term in English to describe the logical concept of a faulty syllogism. That seems to fit EL as I see it.

Comment: @TheNate - It's not faulty until it's shown that Jim is taller than Susan.

Comment: The *syllogism* is faulty, regardless of the truth state, because the *logic* is unsound. The question is, as I read it, what that specific error should be called. (I think the term is something like broken logical implication, but I don't know for certain.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Possible candidates: [association fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy), [ignoratio elenchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoratio_elenchi), [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). The page on "fallacies" may be of general interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies

Comment: @Cerberus - Thank you.  I think Association fallacy is perfect.  I had to accept Mazura's answer because that was the term I was trying to think of but couldn't.  Please post your answer so I can at least up vote it and give you partial credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**non sequitur** –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=non%20sequitur&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> a conclusion or statement that does not logically follow from the previous argument or statement.

---

> A [Non sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_%28logic%29) (Latin for "it does not follow"), in formal logic, is an argument with a conclusion that does not follow from its premises. In a non sequitur, the conclusion could be either true or false (because there is a disconnection between the premise and the conclusion), but the argument nonetheless asserts the conclusion to be true, and is thus fallacious. All **invalid arguments** are special cases of non sequitur. –Wiki

#9:

[image]

([source](http://forums.abcnews.go.com/discussions/Politics/Politics_Board/The_10_Commandments_of_Logic/ABCPolitics/451913.1?redirCnt=1&nav=messages))

Comment: THAT was exactly the term I was looking for!

Comment: I like those ten.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "affirming the consequent", though I'm no logician.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent